# How to limit transmition of ViewState during ajax call

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-2.0, viewstate

Is it possible to get viewstate only for related controls of update panel in asp.net ajax framework. I know that the browser sends all the viewstate during post back, even if we dont need the whole viewstate for ajax calls.

Comment: Don't use ASP.Net Ajax, it's bloated and horrible, the only place you should use it is non-public facing stuff like intranets.

Comment: @Phill Can you please justify your adjectives 'bloated', 'horrible' given to Ajax?

Comment: Not Ajax, to the ASP.Net Ajax. ViewState and Page Lifecycle alone makes it bloated and horrible. I'm not gonna go into detail tho.

Answer (score 2):

no its not possible. this is how asp.net ajax works. you should probably use jquery ajax instead

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this excellent case study of Codeplex, which also used UpdatePanel and suffered from bloated ViewState.

http://encosia.com/2008/12/03/have-you-ever-wondered-why-codeplex-is-so-slow/